# Populating an array with multiple variables c#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to populate an array with an object with multiple variables. What I need is to create an array, not a list(I'm trying to learn arrays), and populate it with 5 different bourbons.  Is it possible to populate the array and store the name, age, distillery in just one index?  For example,

If I called index 0, it would display:

```
Name: Black Maple Hill
Distillery: CVI Brands, Inc
Age: 8 years
```

I have this so far, in which bourbon is a derived class from whiskey and call a method in the main class to prompt user for entry.

```
class Bourbon : Whiskey
{
    private Bourbon[] bBottles = new Bourbon[5];

    public void bourbon(string name, string distillery, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Distillery = distillery;
        Age = age;
     }

    public void PopulateBottles()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Please enter the information for 5 bourbons:");
         for (int runs = 0; runs < 5; runs ++)
         {

         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Dude, first thing you need to learn is express your thoughts in clear way! Divide problem in sections. Provide some context for those who would answer. And this smells like homework.

Comment: You have misguided intuition.  My homework is to create a DVD rental program.  This is me just trying to understand arrays.  

The question seemed to explicitly state what I was looking for.  The grammar was rather accurate and the points I made were introduced in  a logically sequential manner.  

Perhaps I do not express myself in a semantically sound way, though I am attempting to learn the semantics of C#.  But allow me to be as clear as I can:

I want to know if it is possible to store a bourbon object in an array.

Comment: What are these lines supposed to do ? Name = Console.ReadLine();
            bBottles[runs] = value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you haven't defined the `value` variable that you are using inside the for loop. You could create new instances of the class and then store them inside the array:

```
public void PopulateBottles()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the information for 5 bourbons:");
    for (int runs = 0; runs < 5; runs ++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name:");
        var name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Distillery:");
        var distillery = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Age:");
        var age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var bourbon = new Bourbon(name, distillery, age);
        bBottles[runs] = bourbon;
    }
}
```

Also make sure you have defined the `Bourbon` class constructor properly:

```
public Bourbon(string name, string distillery, int age)
{
    Name = name;
    Distillery = distillery;
    Age = age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jonathan. Yes, it is possible, based on my interpretation. You can try making use of indexers.

```
Class Bourbon : Whiskey {
 public Bourbon this[int index]
 {
     get {
         return bBottles[index];
     }
     set {
         bBottles[index] = value;
     }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: How does this handle creating new objects which was missing from the OP's code?

Comment: @ryadavilli. That's the partial code posted. One has to write a parser and construct objects of type, Bourbon. Parser, which reads from Console.

Comment: I get what you have done. I asked that question to get a more complete answer from you. Self explanatory answers with both code and explanation are preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Need to Create Property and One Constructor to achieve your requirement.

```
class Bourbon
    {

        private Bourbon[] bBottles = new Bourbon[5];

        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
        private string distillery;

        public string Distillery
        {
            get { return distillery; }
            set { distillery = value; }
        }
        private int age;

        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set { age = value; }
        }

        public Bourbon(string name, string distillery, int age)
        {
            Name = name;
            Distillery = distillery;
            Age = age;
        }

        public void PopulateBottles()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the information for 5 bourbons:");
            for (int runs = 0; runs < 5; runs++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name:");
                var name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Distillery:");
                var distillery = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Age:");
                var age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                var bourbon = new Bourbon(name, distillery, age);
                bBottles[runs] = bourbon;
            }
        }
    }
```